# Doctrine2 query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 2 entities such as `Country` and `Region`. Here are the entities:

`Country` Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Catalog\Models\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* A country page.
*
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="tbl_country")
* @property string $name
* @property string $code
* @property string $latitude
* @property string $longitude
* @property string $countryLogo
* @property int $id
*/
class Country {

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=250,nullable=true)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=5,nullable=true)
    */
    private $code;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="float",nullable=true)
    */
    private $latitude;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="float",nullable=true)
    */
    private $longitude;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=120,nullable=true)
    */
    private $countryLogo;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Catalog\Models\Entity\Region", mappedBy="country")
    */
    protected $regions;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getCode() {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode($code) {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public function getLatitude() {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    public function setLatitude($latitude) {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
    }

    public function getLongitude() {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    public function setLongitude($longitude) {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    public function getCountryLogo() {
        return $this->countryLogo;
    }

    public function setCountryLogo($countryLogo) {
        $this->countryLogo = $countryLogo;
    }

    public function getRegions() {
        return $this->regions;
    }

    public function setRegions($regions) {
        $this->regions = $regions;
    }

}
```

`Region` Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Catalog\Models\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* A region page.
*
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="tbl_region")
* @property string $name
* @property string $code
* @property string $latitude
* @property string $longitude
* @property int $id
*/
class Region {

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=250,nullable=true)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=5,nullable=true)
    */
    private $code;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="float",nullable=true)
    */
    private $latitude;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="float",nullable=true)
    */
    private $longitude;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalog\Models\Entity\Country", inversedBy="regions")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $country;


    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getCode() {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode($code) {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public function getLatitude() {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    public function setLatitude($latitude) {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
    }

    public function getLongitude() {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    public function setLongitude($longitude) {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    public function getCountry() {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry($country) {
        $this->country = $country;
    }

}
```

I am trying to get all the countries. But when I do like this

```
$countries = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Catalog\Models\Entity\Country')->findAll();
```

It is returning all the countries and regions.

And when I try this

```
$countries = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("SELECT Country.id, Country.name FROM Catalog\Models\Entity\Country Country")->execute();
```

It returns only `Country` in array format. How can I get only the `Country` in Object format?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to mark the regions assosiation as lazy load:

```
 class Country {
     ...
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Catalog\Models\Entity\Region", mappedBy="country", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
     protected $regions;
```

See docs here: https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html?highlight=fetch

Answer (score 0):

The first method should work, but if your want to get your query working you should do like this:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    "SELECT c FROM Catalog\Models\Entity\Country c"
);
$countries = $query->getResult();
```

The problem lies in your select statement. If you want a collection of objects (entities) in your result you should only query for the entity by its alias and not specify properties in the `SELECT` statement. If you do this it will return only the properties you asked for in array format.